# Suggest materials about generation visual studio 2015 diagram (cd) xml source

Tags: visual-studio, t4, envdte

I need some diagrams (cd) with enums and classes, which can be filtered by attributes or so on. It seems that cd file structure is not so complex. I think cd generation could be done automaticaly based on t4 templates.

Please suggest materials (or libraries) about how to generate diagrams (cd) xml source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Directed Graph Markup Language (DGML) for such tasks

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn966108.aspx

Comment: Another part of solution - using Roslyn in T4 https://github.com/newsoftinc/Newsoft.Roslyn.T4